# Making a function template with cv-qualified arguments of this function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a function template:

```
template < typename A, typename B, typename xClass, typename D>
void foo(A& a, B& (xClass::*fooPtr)(D& d));
{
//some code
}
```

I have some classes, which I want to use later as an xClass in my function. But their member functions have different const-qualifiers:

```
const out_t& Class1::foo1(in_t) const // (1)
out_t& Class1::foo1(in_t) // (2) just non-const version of foo1(), making the same actions
out_t& Class2::foo2(in_t) const // (3)
```

Now, if I use

```
... B& (xClass::*fooPtr)(D& d) ...
```

in function template, only pointer to (2) member function makes foo() work, others cause "incompatible cv-qualifiers" error.
Howewer, adding "const" qualifier:

```
... B& (xClass::*fooPtr)(D& d) const ...
```

makes (3) working, but now (2) (and (1) also) causes error.

Is there a simple way to make function foo() to "do not notice" cv-qualifiers of pointers to member functions? I tried to use reinterpret_cast in order to make all necessary pointers to member functions similarly cv-qualified:

```
typedef B& out_t& (Class1::*fooPtr)(in_t) const;
fooPtr myPtr = reinterpret_cast<fooPtr>(&Class1::foo1);
```

but it failed.

Comment: What, if anything, do you use `B` and `D` for?

Comment: D is one of {size_t, int, long int}, and B may be any type.

Comment: That's...not the question. Does your `// some code` make use of these types in anyway? And if so, how?

Comment: "//some code" uses d of type D only to get access to some element of type B in my collection, but then it changes B-type value, so I should not use `const B& (xClass::*fooPtr)(D& d)` pointers in function template.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. Can you show the actual code using empty implementation? Also, I don't understand how you got foo2 to pass? I think there might be a mistake there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make your `foo` function more general, so that it just takes a member pointer of any type:

```
template < typename A, typename F, typename xClass>
void foo(A& a, F xClass::*fooPtr)
{
//some code
}
```

This means that `foo` will accept pointers to data members or member functions that have signatures other than what you want, but it usually isn't that big of a problem.  If you pass the wrong type of member, you'll typically just get a compilation error because the member function can't be called the way you are calling it.  If you want to restrict it more, you can use SFINAE tricks.